# Docker file needs to install nvm without internet gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, shell, dockerfile, nvm

I'm working on a webapp on AWS CodePipeline, and one of my backend pipeline's stages includes a docker build command, and the Dockerfile includes these commands:

```
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
RUN /bin/bash -c ". ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && \
    nvm install $NODE_VERSION && nvm use $NODE_VERSION && \
    npm install -g aws-cdk cdk-assume-role-credential-plugin@1.1.1 && \
    nvm alias default node && nvm cache clear"  

RUN echo export PATH="\
/root/.nvm/versions/node/${NODE_VERSION}/bin:\
$(python3.8 -m site --user-base)/bin:\
$(python3 -m site --user-base)/bin:\
$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc && \
     echo "nvm use ${NODE_VERSION} 1> /dev/null" >> ~/.bashrc
   
RUN /bin/bash -c  ". ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && cdk --version"

ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-c", ". ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && uvicorn cdkproxymain:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080" ]
```

The problem is that I'm running code in a VPC without an internet gateway (client's policy), so the curl command fails. I have tried to install nvm locally by copying the nvm folder to my `src` directory, but I lack the skills to script this.

Any advice is welcome, Thank you so much !

Comment: Can you use a base image that has node already installed? In a container `nvm` does not make much sense.

Comment: Thanks ! I'm going to look into this as well.
Ideally i'd like to keep as close to the original code as possible, so using nvm would be great